# scatter plot html5/javascript library that allows setting color & alpha for each point

Tags: javascript, html, colors, alpha, scatter-plot

I'm looking for a free scatter plot html5/javascript library that allows setting color & alpha for each point.

I know that http://www.rgraph.net/ has this functionality, but I'm looking for a library with a less restrictive license.

Comment: jqPlot (http://www.jqplot.com) allows you to color each series independently, so depending on your exact requirements, you may be able to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably accomplish this using Raphael.js.  Here's a sample scatter plot from their demo site:
http://raphaeljs.com/github/dots.html

And you might consider using this as a jumping-off point:
https://github.com/stringfellow/raphael-scatter

Answer (score 0):

RGraph ( https://www.rgraph.net ) is MIT licensed now - totally free.